# rsync -ru does not copy latest version from two sources to one destination

Tags: rsync

I have two drives I normally use. One main drive -A- and another as a backup -B- when the first one is full.

Then I have a third larger -C- drive which I have tried to rsync to from both source drives, but I keep finding it copies any file date and not the latest.

If I on the Linux box run

rsync -ru A/ C and then run

rsync -ru B/ C

it does not check if the file on -A- or -B- is older or younger so I can end up with an older or newer file on -C- depending on how good I have been with copying files from A to B earlier.

For instance

A/file.txt updated yesterday

B/file.txt updated last week

rsync will first copy yesterdays file to C and then overwrite it with last weeks file from B, whereas I want the latest file period.

I want

C/file.txt updated yesterday and not

C/file.txt updated last week regardless if that file was on A or B.

Is it possible with the right flags? Or do I have to only do rsync from one drive A or B to C?

I tried and I tried and I failed

Comment: Is the modification time of the files on C actually correct? I think you need to include `-t|--times` to preserve the modification time or else rsync will ignore `-u`.

Comment: I will try this option when I run it again. Crossing my mutated fingers.